# Enable VRFY verb in Exchange 2007

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007

Is there a way to enable the VRFY command on the Exchange server. I know this command is a security risk, but the server sits behind a firewall, and is not accessible from the internet. I would just use it as an inbox. The mail traffic would be forwarded from my home coded SMTP server, which would check for the existence of the exchange inbox with the VRFY command.

I only found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289521) on the internet, but this is only for legacy versions of Exhange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, mostly no.

VRFY is there, in that Exchange 2007 will reply to it, but it only ever replies "252 2.1.5 Cannot VRFY user, but will take message for m0sa@example.com".